# Reactjs code runs very on windows but introduces error on linux

Tags: reactjs

The code below run very on windows but when I upload it to online server and run usual npm run build or npm start it introduces syntaxerror unexpected token. I do not know why linux is doing do that. The eror seems to be pointing at BrowserRouter Element here is the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './components/App.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';

// Require Sass file so webpack can build it
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import style from './styles/style.css';

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Did you forget `npm install`? Or maybe the `.bablerc`? It doesn't understand JSX yet. You need to transpile with bable.

Comment: are you having same version of node js on Windows and Linux? And same version of packages?

Comment: I have run npm install and packages  are the same as in package.json

Comment: Thanks @ colburton the issue is that .bablerc is missing

Answer (score 0):

I tested it as follows and discovered that the issue was due to lack of `.bablerc` files as Colburton suggested for fast troubleshooting I
set up the following libraries in the `index.html` files.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

I then pass `type="text/babel"` attribute to the script tags as follows:

```
<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))

</script>
```